# CSS: How to address specific tags

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm just beginning to learn CSS (and XHTML) and I ran into a problem of assigning different properties to tags which have the same tag name.

For example: I have two h3 headers, but want to address them specifically using CSS because I want to make them different colours.

I believe this has something to do with naming the headers differently (i.e. h3.a), but trying this didnt work. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides the tag name CSS can be applied by Class and ID.  Note that it's best to make sure the case in your  tags matches the case in the tags.

.myClass may not apply to class="myclass"

IDs:

```
<style>
#FirstHeading {color: red;}
#SecondHeader {color: blue;}
</style>

<h3 id="FirstHeading"></h3>
<h3 id="SecondHeader"></h3>
```

Classes:
    
    .redHeading {color: red;}
    .blueHeader {color: blue;}

```
<h3 class="redHeading"></h3>
<h3 class="blueHeader"></h3>
```

The purpose of IDs are typically to point to one specific element in your page, classes are designed to work with multiple different elements

Classes can also be combined, so you don't need to load all the styles into one class.

```
<style>
.redHeading {color: red;}
.blueHeader {color: blue;}
.boldHeader {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<h3 class="redHeading boldHeader"></h3>
<h3 class="blueHeader boldHeader"></h3>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can assign a class to each element and use CSS to target only that class.  For example:

**HTML:**

```
<h3 class="green">Green heading for this one</h3>
<h3 class="red">Red heading for this.</h3>
```

**CSS:**

```
h3.green { color:green; }
h3.red { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 5):

There are so many different ways to target selectors.

You can give them class names:

```
<h3 class="makeblue">This should be blue</h3>
<h3 class="makegreen">This should be green</h3>

// in you css
h3.makeblue { color: blue; }
h3.makegreen { color: green; }
```

You can use "advanced selectors":

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>This should be blue</h3>
    <p>
        <h3>This should be green</h3>
    </p>
</div>

// in your css
div.container > h3 { color: blue; }
div.container p h3 { color: green; }
```

have a look here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Answer (score 3):

Add different `class` attributes to each `h3`, then address them in CSS using `.className`.

e.g:

HTML:

```
<h3 class="class1">One header</h3>
<h3 class="class2">Another header</h3>
```

CSS:

```
.class1 {
    color: #00f;
}
.class2 {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is where classes come in handy.

CSS

```
.myFirstClass { color:green; }
.mySecondClass { color:red; }
```

HTML

```
<h3 class="myFirstClass">Text</h3>
<h3 class="mySecondClass">Text</h3>
```

Comment: One note about class names is you never want to be specific with the names when it comes to color or usage because those things may change over time. We had a button class named `.button-green` for our green buttons...then they decided they wanted blue buttons instead and `.button-green` became a blue button. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS by addressing a tag you address all copies of that tag unless you are more specific.

e.g.

`a h3 {}` would address all `h3` tags within an `a` tag.

However if you want to style individual elements or want more freedom you should be using a `class` or an `id`.

An `id` can be used on one element and works like so:

```
<h3 id="header"></h3>
```

you can then use

```
#header {
 // your css style here 
}
```

to style it.

Or you can use a class which can be used on multiple elements like so:

```
<h3 class="red"></h3>
<a class="red"></a>
```

you can then use

```
.red {
  // your css style here
}
```

to style it.

Google provides some good video tutorials here: [HTML, CSS and Javascript from the ground up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#css)

Answer (score 2):

A useful thing to keep in mind when naming classes is to avoid names that imply how the class is styled. Naming classes after their styles leaks design information into the HTML, and if you later do a redesign, you will either have class names that no longer match the design, or you will have to edit both the HTML and the CSS to keep it up to date.

A much better practice is to create classes with semantic meaning, such as: `subtitle`, `navigationHeader` etc. Additionally, it's a good practice to give multiple classes and thus "extend" objects instead of repeating yourself:

```
<h2 class="subtitle forum">Forum</h2>
<h2 class="subtitle group">Groups</h2>

.subtitle {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

.subtitle.forum {
  color: blue;
}

.subtitle.group {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks! Question though, I don't see you addressing either of the h2 tags in the CSS. you have .subtitle, .subtitle.group, and .subtitle.forum, but no ".subtitle forum" or ".subtitle group". why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a class in CSS, like this:

```
h3.class1
{
color: blue;
}
```

Then just say:

```
<h3 class="class1"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class or a parent to define it. If you use a class it would be defined like:

```
h3.colorOne {
    color: #ff0000;
}

h3.colorTwo {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Then they would be used like:

```
<h3 class="colorOne">I'm red</h3>
<h3 class="colorTwo">I'm blue</h3>
```

Alternatively you can specify settings by a parent using an id field in a div of sorts:

```
#divOne h3 {
    color: #ff0000;
}

#divTwo h3 {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Which would be used like:

```
<div id="colorOne"><h3>I'm red</h3></div>
<div id="colorTwo"><h3>I'm blue</h3></div>
```

The usage all depends on the needs of your layout and the extensibility of your styles.